# Connecting Excel to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to write a function which will tell if Excel VBA has a reference set to Outlook:

```
Function RefOutlook() As Boolean

    Application.Volatile

    On Error Resume Next

    If olFolderInbox=6 Then
            RefOutlook = True
        Else
            RefOutlook = False
    End If

End Function
```

My logic is that if a reference is established, VBA will recognise an Outlook built-in constant olFolderInbox (equal to 6) and will return True, otherwise there will be an error and the function shall return False. The problem is that if there is no reference, the error is not suppressed, an error message comes up and the function is not working.

Many thanks in advance for your feedback and suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you try latebinding so you don't need to have the reference?

Comment: I have some code dealing with Outlook which is rather complex and requires early binding. I want to have a function which will tell users there is no reference to Outlook and they need to set it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if they try to run a code without the reference, the code won't even compile, giving a compile error...

Comment: That's why I want this function to serve as an early warning and I might build some error-handling routine into my main code as well.

Comment: You could loop through all your loaded references and check if you have the one needed, like they show [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/62123-check-if-ref-library-is-loaded/&postID=575116#post575116)

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to specify [Option Strict Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) in the beginning of VBA modules. Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.
When `Option Strict On` or `Option Strict` appears in a file, the following conditions cause a compile-time error:

- Implicit narrowing conversions
- Late binding
- Implicit typing that results in an `Object` type

So, you will get a compile-time error if the Outlook reference is not added.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use early binding for development, and convert to late binding when deploying your application. By doing so, you not only avoid the problem of constants not being available, but also any versioning issues.

When you do so, you will need to replace any constants, such as `olFolderInbox`, with your own global constants:

```
Global Const OL_FOLDER_INBOX = 1
```

Regards,